# grep and sed only the numbers from a text file's line

Tags: text-processing, grep, sed

I'd like to extract only a number from a text file. It is like:

```
corner_lat:     49.0425000  decimal degrees
```

I am using the following expression :

```
grep corner_lat EQA.dem_par | sed "s,[^0-9]*,,"
```

but this gives back also the "decimal degrees"
How can modify this to get only the number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `g` (global substitution) to replace all occurrences of pattern you are looking for:

```
grep corner_lat EQA.dem_par | sed "s/[^0-9.]*//g"
```

or as you wrote it:

```
grep corner_lat EQA.dem_par | sed "s,[^0-9.]*,,g"
```

Don't forget to add `.` in character class otherwise it will be removed too.

Your command only removes first occurrence of the pattern which is:

```
corner_lat:
```

And leaving:

```
49.0425000  decimal degrees
```

Answer (score 1):

If the format of all lines in the file is the same, you can use `awk` or `cut` instead of `sed` to extract only the second colum.

As an example:

```
grep corner_lat EQA.dem_par | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: May be  `awk '/^corner_lat:/ {print $2}'`